# XSLT copy and rename a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to insert and rename some elements of parent- and sibling nodes with XSLT but can't get the job done.

This is my XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<file>
<student_id>163</student_id>
<report>
    <final>false</final>
    <period>1</period>
    <year>2015</year>
    <variant>
        <type>Country</type>
        <value>Netherlands</value>
    </variant>
    <grade>
        <value>8</value>
        <topic>french</topic>
    </grade>
    <grade>
        <value>7</value>
        <topic>dutch</topic>
    </grade>
</report>
</file>
```

This is my desired XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><file>
<student_id>163</student_id>
<report>
    <final>false</final>
    <period>1</period>
    <year>2015</year>
    <variant>
        <variant_type>Country</variant_type>
        <variant_value>Netherlands</variant_value>
    </variant>
    <grade>
        <student_id>163</student_id>
        <final>false</final>
        <period>1</period>
        <year>2015</year>           
        <variant_type>Country</variant_type>
        <variant_value>Netherlands</variant_value>
        <value>8</value>
        <topic>french</topic>
    </grade>
    <grade>
        <student_id>163</student_id>
        <final>false</final>
        <period>1</period>
        <year>2015</year>           
        <variant_type>Country</variant_type>
        <variant_value>Netherlands</variant_value>  
        <value>7</value>
        <topic>dutch</topic>
    </grade>
</report>
</file>
```

Please note that type and value under file/student/variant should be renamed to variant_type and variant_value and copied over to their sibling grade. Student_id, final, period, and year should also be copied over to grade.

I am trying to achieve this by using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template><xsl:template match="variant/type">
<variant_type>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</variant_type></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="variant/value">
<variant_value>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</variant_value></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="grade">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../../student_id"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../final"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../period"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../year"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../variant/variant_type"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../variant/variant_value"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the above XSLT  and variant/value are renamed.. but not inserted in grade as such. Only student_id, final, period, and year are included. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="variant/type">
    <variant_type>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </variant_type>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="variant/value">
    <variant_value>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </variant_value>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="grade">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../student_id"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../final"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../period"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../year"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../variant/*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:
The result is slightly different from the one you requested, because yours is not well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these lines in the template matching `grade`:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../variant/variant_type"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="../variant/variant_value"/>
```

You are trying to copy the elements `../variant/variant_type` and `../variant/variant_value` but **these elements do not exist in your input file**; as you want to copy *the renamed elements you created*, you must use instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../variant/type"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="../variant/value"/>
```

so that you will find the elements `../variant/type` and `../variant/value` in the input file, and apply the renaming logic you already defined.